# Accessing the array outside the loop

Tags: python

I am using python after a long time. I wrote a code that looks like this:

```
for i in range(mem_max):
    for j in range(nx):
        temp = []
        for k in range(ny):
            temp.append(table[i][j][k])
        print temp
    print ("\n")
```

I want to access the temp array [] outside the main for loop. I tried to use the "return", however did not seem to help. Can anyone please share some ideas? Somehow I cannot define the temp[] outside due to nature of the code.

Comment: Like I mentioned due to nature of my code

Comment: What do you mean you can't define it outside?  "The nature of the code" is veryyyyy vague.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: @C.B. There is no local scope for loops in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use it. Python isn't C, its flow of control statements don't define scope.

```
for i in range(10):
    temp = []
    temp.append(i)

print temp
```

http://ideone.com/m4mX9y

Although, it may not have the semantics you want.

Comment: I think the issue is that the OP keeps overwriting the data from the previous loop iteration when they do `temp = []`.  They probably want to access all the data they added, so they need to only do `temp = []` at the beginning of the outer loop.

Comment: @SethMMorton, the OP clearly stated their question. I gave a fair warning in the end. However, if one knows what they are doing, it will not be a cause for a problem. I added my answer because it's important to differentiate between Python and C (which few seem to do). You *can* access the variable even if it's created inside a loop, but it may not have the same semantics as when you declare it up front.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the array before the start of the outer loop.

```
temp = []
for i in range......
```

when you declare temp inside of the loop; it is recreated as an empty array

Comment: I think you should specify "before the start of the *outer* loop"